# WebView Class (Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls) does not support WebAuthn in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, webauthn

I have a WPF application using WebView class to launch browser. My need is to load a url that invokes WebAuthn functionality. Target URL is https://demo.yubico.com. But I get the error as browser not supported?[image]

Is there any work around for the same?

Comment: See my new answer below. Can you expand a bit on what mechanism/protocol you're using for the browser-based sign in flow?

Answer (score 0):

I'd misread the original question as pertaining to Xamarin - my apologies.

In this case it's strongly recommended to use the system default browser for browser-based authentication flows:

This RFC covers best practice for OAuth2 and native apps and I think it's relevant here:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252